# Post and submit problems using javascript, forms and php

Tags: php, javascript, html, forms, email-validation

I am trying to create a validate-email javascript and get it working with forms and PHP. Of coures, some problems...

1. As you can see in my form, I did define "post" as the method. But I can only retreive the data as if it was a get method. It was working before I started to add the e-mail verification script and adopt the code to it.
2. If the e-mail is incorrect, I do return false. Isn't the point that the request to the test.php (defined in action) should not be executed? As it is now, the page is accessed even if I return false.
3. Depending on the answers to the questions above, do I need to submit the form from the Javascript if the e-mail is verified ok?

javascript:

```
function isValidEmail() {
    regExp = /^[a-zA-Z]+([_\.-]?[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*@[a-zA-Z0-9]+([\.-]?[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4})+$/;
 if(document.subscribe.email1.value.search(regExp) == -1){
          alert(document.subscribe.email1.value + " Incorrect email address");
    return false; 
    } 

//document.subscribeForm.submit();

return true; 
}
```

php:

```
<?php

echo $_POST['email1'];

$mysqli = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "test", "3306");

$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT email, id, subscriber, subscribed_date FROM `user` u;");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
foreach($row as $key => $value){

   echo "$key = $value<BR/>";
}
}

mysqli_free_result($result);
mysqli_close($mysqli);

?>
```

html:

```
<div id="subscribe">
  <form action="test.php" name="subscribe" method=post">
    <p id="formlabel">E-mail</p> <input type="text" name="email1">
    <br>
    <p id="formlabel">Repeat e-mail</p> <input type="text" name="email2"> <br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Subscribe" onclick="isValidEmail()">
  </form>
```

Comment: Stop. Please stop. Validating email addresses is a hard problem. Your code already has false positives (e.g. it will block any email address on a *.museum domain). If you want to see if an email address is genuine — send an email to it and require the user to click a link with a unique token in it.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I am aware of the lacking *.museum. Perhaps your idea is the one I should stick with, I need to consider that.

Comment: Or indeed `.travel`, or any of the eleven new IDNA TLDs. In general you don't want to have to worry about updating all your applications when a new TLD is introduced!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<input type="submit" value="Subscribe" onclick="isValidEmail()">
```

This executes `isValidEmail()` and then throws away the result. The `onclick` itself returns `undefined` and the submission is not prevented.

You can say `onclick="return isValidEmail()"`. However:

1. Put validation/submission stuff on `form onsubmit`, not `input click`, to ensure it is always called for all types of form submission.
2. Better to avoid inline event handlers.
3. You missed a `"` in your form's `method` attribute, which is presumably why it was defaulting back to `get`.

so:

```
<form id="subscribe" method="post" action="test.php">
    ...
</form>

<script type="text/javascript>
    document.getElementById('subscribe').onsubmit= function() {
        if (!this.elements.email1.value.match(/^[^@]+@[^@]+$/) {
            alert('Please enter an e-mail address');
            return false;
        }
        if (this.elements.email1.value!=this.elements.email2.value) {
            alert('E-mail addresses do not match');
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    } 
</script>
```

I replaced the regexp with a trivial one, because the expression you're currently using is bogus and will deny *many* valid e-mail addresses. Turning customers away because their e-mail address doesn't fit your conception of what an e-mail address is sucks.

‘Validating’ e-mail addresses correctly with regex [is absurdly difficult](http://www.ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html). Better to include only a trivial check for obviously-malformed strings like the above. If you need to really check the e-mail address, you will have to actually try to send a mail to it, or at least try to lookup the domain name part of the address for an MXer.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-for-validating-email-addresses) for discussion.

Comment: Thanks! Using the input line as described above isn't really working, as soon as I click the texfield the script is called. onsubmit works nicely though.

Comment: Did see your update. I only need a trivial one, this is not for verifying transfers-of-money-important-kind-of-activity, just to subscribe to a newsletter. Thanks again!

Comment: Even for a newsletter, you might want to avoid false negatives.

Answer (score 2):

you should attach the function to the form's onsubmit event:

```
<form action="test.php" name="subscribe" method="post" onsubmit="isValidEmail()">
```

where you can stop the event returning false.
Also, you made a typo in method=post", that's why it doesn't get submitted as POST data.

Comment: bobince's answer below is more complete

Comment: Yes! If you are thinking about that I marked your answer as the "answer", I choosed the one that answered first and who's answered helped me. Perhaps the principle is to choose the most complete answer instead of the fastest that helped out, please let me know if that is the principle to use!

Comment: I'm new here, so I am no expert, but I guess it would be ideal to mark the most useful solution as answer, useful as for future reference.
So if you can change the "anwser", I'd chose bobince's - you can still give me an upvote for fast reply I guess ;)